# rsyslog log file with wildcards

Tags: amazon-ecs, rsyslog

configure rsyslog to monitor direcory files when log file name changed

I have a service that creates a new log file each hour with the hour in the file name i.e: ecs-agent.log.2019-03-26-08 
Each time the file changed rsyslog doesnt recognize the change.
the following settings in the conf file will not work:

```
$InputFileName /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.*
$InputFileStateFile stat-ecs-agent.log.*
```

Since there is only one log file in the folder active each time - anyway to configure rsyslog to monitor the folder?